# How to dynamically get the parameter values from a procedure or method in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

The goal is to write a method that will allow me to easily log input parameter values.  I know I can do this manually, but I am trying to figure out if I can do this dynamically.  So far by looking on the internet it seems like the answer is no.
I am currently working with Oracle 12.1.0.2.0.

Sample code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_t1( i_a VARCHAR2, i_b VARCHAR2 )
AS
   v_sql_1      VARCHAR2( 2000 );
   v_sql_2      VARCHAR2( 2000 );
   v_output_1   VARCHAR2( 2000 );
   v_output_2   VARCHAR2( 2000 );
   v_args       VARCHAR2( 2000 );
BEGIN
   SELECT    ''''''''' || '
          || LISTAGG( '''[' || a.argument_name || '='' || ' || a.argument_name || ' || '']''', ' || '', '' || ' )
                WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.sequence)
          || '|| '''''''''
             AS args
     INTO v_args
     FROM user_arguments a
    WHERE a.object_name = 'PR_T1'
      AND in_out LIKE '%IN%'
      AND a.sequence = 1;

   v_sql_1 := 'BEGIN SELECT ' || '''[i_a=' || i_a || ']''' || ' INTO :p1 FROM DUAL; END;'; -- works
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'v_sql_1: ' || v_sql_1 );

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_1 USING OUT v_output_1;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'v_output: ' || v_output_1 );

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( '----------------------------------------------------' );

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'v_args: ' || v_args );

   v_sql_2 := 'BEGIN SELECT ' || v_args || ' INTO :p1 FROM DUAL; END;';
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'v_sql_2: ' || v_sql_2 );

   --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_2 USING OUT v_output_2; -- How to make this work?
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'v_output_2: ' || v_output_2 );
END pr_t1;

    -------------------------------
    -- Call the procedure
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

    EXEC pr_t1('1', '2');
```

Sample Result:

```
v_sql_1: BEGIN SELECT '[i_a=1]' INTO :p1 FROM DUAL; END;
v_output: [i_a=1]
----------------------------------------------------
v_args: '''' || '[I_A=' || I_A || ']'|| ''''
v_sql_2: BEGIN SELECT '''' || '[I_A=' || I_A || ']'|| '''' INTO :p1 FROM DUAL; END;
v_output_2:
```

I am trying to figure out what can I do such that I can dynamically make "v_sql_2" to have the value of "1".

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you try to show in your example. Would you like to log all the parameters and values passed on into a table or somewhere or would you like to reuse a variable value in a SQL statement? In the example above you seem to concatenate twice the variable name into the SELECT list based on your SELECT into v_args. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @gvenzl I am trying to log all the parameters and values passed on into a table.  The reason why the concatenation happens twice (or at least what I am trying to accomplish) is to store the parameter with the first and the value with the second.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Pranav, that makes more sense to me now. And do you want that to be logged in general at runtime or only for debug/trace or are you just looking for a dynamic way of logging parameters and values of them in your PL/SQL?

Comment: @gvenzl Ideally I want to log method, parameter name and values dynamically at runtime.  But it would be interesting to learn the debug/trace option as well.